# Populate a selected list from another selected list in one View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I have a database with this relationship:
1 Projekt can have Many Referenz.
1 Referenze can have Many Datei.

Im trying to populate 2 list on a view page (Edit Projekt). The first list is the Referenz :-

```
 ViewBag.referenz = new SelectList(db.FileRefObj.Where(x => x.ProjectId == id).ToList(), "FileReferenz", "FileReferenz");
```

How do I populate the Datei list , where it should contain a list where the ReferenzId exist in the first list?

```
ViewBag.datei = new SelectList(db.DateiObj.Where(x => x.ReferenzId == ?? ).ToList(), "DateiName", "DateiName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Any() method from List<T> class for that purpose. As documented:

> Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

> Returns: True if any elements in the source sequence pass the test in
> the specified predicate; otherwise, False.

With that said, I would first cache your list as List, rather than SelectList:

```
var referenzList = db.FileRefObj.Where(x => x.ProjectId == id).ToList();
ViewBag.referenz = new SelectList(referenzList, "FileReferenz", "FileReferenz");
```

Then I would Any() my way out of the first cached List instead, like that:

```
var dateiList = db.DateiObj.Where(x => referenzList.Any(y => y.ReferenzId == x.ReferenzId)).ToList();
ViewBag.datei = new SelectList(dateiList, "DateiName", "DateiName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I can propose several ways:

**Server side**

```cs
var fileReferenz = db.FileRefObj.Where(x => x.ProjectId == id);

ViewBag.referenz = new SelectList(fileReferenz, "FileReferenz", "FileReferenz");

var datei = db.DateiObj
    .Where(x => fileReferenz.Select(r => r.ReferenzId).Contains(r => x.ReferenzId == r);

ViewBag.datei = new SelectList(datei, "DateiName", "DateiName");
```

**Mixed**

Difference here that we retrieve FileRefObj to the client and use ids for filtering.

```cs
var fileReferenz = db.FileRefObj.Where(x => x.ProjectId == id).ToList();

ViewBag.referenz = new SelectList(fileReferenz, "FileReferenz", "FileReferenz");

var datei = db.DateiObj
    .Where(x => fileReferenz.Select(r => r.ReferenzId).Contains(r => x.ReferenzId == r);

ViewBag.datei = new SelectList(datei, "DateiName", "DateiName");
```

**Using `Include`**

```cs
var fileReferenz = db.FileRefObj
   .Include(x => x.Datei)
   .Where(x => x.ProjectId == id)
   .ToList();

ViewBag.referenz = new SelectList(fileReferenz, "FileReferenz", "FileReferenz");

var datei = fileReferenz.SelectMany(x => x.Datei);

ViewBag.datei = new SelectList(datei, "DateiName", "DateiName");
```